# How to draw a sequential logic circuit from any given state diagram?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, sequential-logic

Could someone point out to me a resource to learn how to draw a sequential logic circuit from any given state diagram or could you tell me how to do it?  I am a non-native English speaker. So please use easy wording.

Even one with 2 or more inputs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to describe, but not necessarily the most compact, is

- Use one-hot encoding for the states. That's one latch per state, that latch on, all other latches off.
- For every arrow into a state, use a gate on the set line that performs the logic operation that's written on the arrow, and sends the inverse of that to the reset input of all the other latches

You may be able to reduce the number of latches by a binary or some other more compact encoding than one-hot. For instance, your illustrated two state machine could use a single latch, with 0 for state 0, and 1 for state 1